# Stepping down as mod

Tags: discussion

I wanted to let y'all know that I requested to step down as a mod recently, and it looks like my diamond has now been *poof*-d after the requisite 6-8 weeks (actually much shorter than that, thank you CMs <3)

A lot has changed in the last 3(!) years - in my personal life, the world, and SE - and I've simply been feeling burnt out. I kept waffling back and forth on the decision to resign, but ultimately, I felt guilty keeping the diamond yet knowing I wasn't serving the community how I wanted to be. Plus I have all confidence that the current mod team will continue to do a great job :)

I've learned so much from everyone here, and I'm so grateful for the experience. Being a mod has at times felt like a crash course in interpersonal skills (let's see... [conflict-aversion](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-aversion) [cross-culture](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-culture) [online-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interaction)... to name a few). For the time being though, I'm happy to be back to a regular user - see you on the main site?

Answer (score 4):

You were a great mod and I thank you for everything you contributed to this site. I am myself not that much active here nowaday, but I do hope that I'll have the pleasure to see you on main :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the time working behind (and on) the scene. Always loved your delicate way of acting, glad being part of this adventure for the past, and hopefully, future, years with you :))

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I'm glad to have been part of it, this community is something special :)